# Casting Config class to OrderedDict in Python

Tags: python, casting, ordereddictionary

Would it be ok to cast an instance of the [Config](http://www.red-dove.com/config/index.html) class (which inherits `Container` and `Mapping`) into `OrderedDict`? I did this and it works without any problem as of now, but can I expect any other bugs as a result of doing this in the future?

If this is not good practice, how can I extract just the dictionary in the class instance to an `OrderedDict`?

Thanks!

EDIT:

Here's a stripped-down version of what I'm doing:

```
from config import Config                         
from collections import OrderedDict               
from itertools import product, izip               

file_name = 'some-config-file.cfg'                
my_cfg_dict = OrderedDict(Config(file(file_name)))

def my_product(dicts):                            
    return (OrderedDict(izip(dicts, e))           
        for e in product(*dicts.itervalues()))

my_cfg_list = my_product(my_cfg_dict)             

for e in my_cfg_list:                             
    print e
```

where `some-config-file.cfg` is something like the following:

```
param1: ['foo', 'bar', 'baz']
param2: ['FOO']
param3: [1, 5, 2]
```

I'm working with `my_cfg_list` in the end. The reason why I chose to cast (again, please forgive me for using the wrong word) the instance of `Config` to `OrderedDict` was because it would work with my_product. As you'll see, it doesn't give me errors now and the behaviour is as expected. I was wondering if it might result in a bug at a later stage, and if there is a more elegant way of doing it.

I hope this clarifies my question some more. Please let me know if any more information is needed. Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "typecast"? Python is not Java or C++, it does not have casting. Show the code you are using.

Comment: Pardon my improper use of the word, but I was only following the example of several other stackoverflow posts which referred to what I wished to do as casting. Please have a look at the updated post. I hope this is up to standard. Could you also tell me what would be a better word to use in place of "casting"? Like converting, or something else?

Comment: Well, `Config` seems to have the methods of a `dict` (which is the pythonic [duck typing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing)), which means that you can indeed convert it to an `OrderedDict` as you have. But do you really care about the `ordered` part?

Comment: Thanks! It turns out I should, going by this guy's warning: http://blog.amir.rachum.com/blog/2013/07/03/python-hash-id-and-dictionary-order/ which I came across in another stackoverflow post. I'm iterating through the items to produce file names with the keys and their corresponding values to save data, and I'll be later using the same type of dictionaries to re-generate these file names and load the previously saved files.